# Relative velocity question, explanation needed

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, relative-motion

This is not a technically complex question but just a matter of perspective while solving. I am unable to comprehend the solution given by my teacher. The topic is relative velocity.
The question is

> Town A and town B are connected with a regular bus service. A bus leaves in either direction every T seconds. A boy cycling with a speed of $10$ Km/hr from town A to town B notices that a bus crosses him after every 15 minutes towards B and every 5 minutes towards A. Calculate time T and speed of buses. Assume that speed of buses is constant.

The solution given by my teacher is

> Let speed of the bus = $v$ km/hr
>
> Relative velocity of bus with respect to cyclist going from:
>
> A to B = $v-10$ km/hr
>
> B to A = $v+10$ km/hr
>
> After T time, a bus is leaving the bus stop, so distance travelled by bus in time T = $vT$
>
> Time =Distance/Speed
>
> $15 min = $$\frac{vT}{v-10}$
>
> $1/4 = $$\frac{vT}{v-10}$
>
> (15 min = ¼ of an hour)
>
> Similarly, 
>   $\frac{1}{12}$= $\frac{vT}{v+10}$
>
> Solving these simultaneous equations,
>   T = $7.5$ min.
>   v = $20$ km/hr

But what I don't seem to get is how did we form those equations? That does not make any intuitive sense to me, neither do I seem to understand how does this work. Can someone elaboratively explain me this, or give an alternative approach to this question?
Thank you.

Comment: I see 11 equations and the question "how did we form those equations?".  Which equations are you asking about?

Answer (score 1):

Let's switch to the bus's point of view. It makes this easier. Assume there are two buses who have both taken off. The separation between the two buses **at any moment of time** will be $vT$. This is because the first bus had taken off $T$ mins before the second bus, and hence gained a separation $vT$ over the second bus.

Switch to the first bus's point of view (the one which is ahead). The second bus is at rest in this frame and is located at a distance $vT$ behind. The cyclist is approaching both buses at a speed $v+15$. The time taken by the cyclist to cover the separation between the buses will be :

$$t=\frac{vT}{v+15}$$

This $t$ is the value that you're given.

Answer (score 0):

From the symmetry of the problem following are same for buses for A to B and B to A

1. speed, say v
2. distance between them say, d (=vT obviously)

now when you cycle in the direction of buses motion then relative speed is (v-10) and when opposite it is (v+10)

you cover the distance 'd' in 15 or 5 min depending on direction

Answer (score 0):

You will have to draw a picture for each of the two scenarios. Please use the following notation: [image]

- velocity of the bike: $v_1 = const$
- velocity of the bus: $v_2 = const$
- Assuming that a bus is just crossing the bike, $s_0$ is the distance between the bike and the **next** bus.
- in the duration $T$ the bike travels the distance: $s_1 = v_1 \cdot T$
- in the duration $T$ the bus travels the distance: $s_2$

You gonna have to draw the second picture, but I'll walk you trough the explanation.

In fact there are two ways to do the calculations. I believe it would help you to do both. The first way is the conceptional simpler one, but you have to do more math. You simply write down the equation for the bus to travel the distance $s_2 = s_0 \pm s_1$, where $s_1$ are the two times you provided. You will get the same equations as we get below. The second one is the one your teacher used. So I gonna explain that one.

Let's assume the bike is denying that it travels at all (we transform into the "rest frame" of the bike -- the bike is at rest $= 0m/s$). The initial distance between the bike and the bus is $s_0$ but the bus now travels only with the relative velocity $\Delta v = v_2 - v_1$. Thus we get 
$$s_0 = (v_2 - v_1) T_1$$
where $T_1 = 15min$.

In the picture you have to draw the bus and the bike drive towards each another. Again, let's assume that the bike denies the fact that it is moving. The initial distance between them is again $s_0$, however, now the bus travels with the relative velocity $\Delta v = v_2 + v_1$. Thus we get 
$$s_0 = (v_2 + v_1) T_2$$
where $T_2 = 5min$. Since we have the same $s_0$ on the left hand side, the two right hand sides must be equal. Thus, we write
$$(v_2 - v_1) T_1 = (v_2 + v_1) T_2$$
The only unknown in this equation is $v_2$. Therefore, we solve for $v_2$.

**Remark**: There is so much wrong in the way you stated the equations in your question. I strongly doubt that your teacher wrote it down this way. So I suspect you missed the explanations and just copied what was written on the blackboard. Try to pay attention to the oral information.

Comment: How is the initial distance between bike and bus in the case **again $S0$**, shouldn't it be total minus $S0$ because $S0$ is distance between A and cyclist.

Comment: I believe this might be the key to your problem. Why do you think that the distance between the cyclist and the final destination matters? If you look at my picture, there is no reference to $A$ or $B$. The important distance is the one between the two buses. If you understand my point, please explain it in a comment, so that other people can profit as well.

Comment: I still don't seem to get why the distance between cyclist and town doesn't matter  :/

Comment: Can you post a picture with the diagram of second scenario?

Comment: Hey what if I deny the motion of bus instead!

Comment: Then the cyclist would be moving with a velocity 10-v backwards, encountering a bus of TOWN A each 15 minutes, and a bus of TOWN B each 5 minutes, tell me I'm right!

Comment: OK, let's take an other example. You see a friend at a distance $s_0$. He/she walks with the speed $v_1$ and didn't notice you. You start running with velocity $v_2$. Now calculate the time it takes you to reach him/her for the two cases: He/she walks away from you and towards you.

Comment: It takes S0/(v2-v1) if he's going away from me and S0/(v2+v1) if he's coming towards me.

Comment: yes, and this is exactly what we get in your bus-bike problem, too. All that matters is the distance between two buses. It doesn't matter when the buses start to drive or how far the bike is from the final destination.

Answer (score 0):

We can immediately see, that the main problem presented in this exercise is the relative velocity.
$$\text{In general, the relative velocity is given by}:\vec v_1-\vec v_2$$
You can think of this rule as simply adding up two vectors. It can be easily verified that if object you are observing is moving in the same direction as you, it's velocity will be reduced by the amount of speed you are moving with. If the object is moving opposite direction it's velocity will have negative sign, thus equation becomes:
$$\vec v_1-(-\vec v_2)=\vec v_1+\vec v_2$$
then the measured velocity from your moving reference frame will be 'boosted' by the speed you are moving with.

> *#Please keep in mind that we are considering non-relativistic motion.*

Note, that in order to measure the velocity, first we need to define the coordinate system. 
We can think the most convenient origin of our coordinate system is the bike, since the entire 'action' happens from boy's view.

But sometimes we get more insight if we look at the problem 'from a backstage', thus we set our observation point in stationary reference frame.

Without loss of generality, assume, that the distance from town A to town B is such, that a single bus travels from a boy's perspective in 15 min if it is moving in direction with him and in 5 min it is moving opposite to him.

We are ready to set up first equations:
$$s_{ab}=t_1(v-v_0)$$
$$s_{ba}=t_2(v+v_0)$$
where:
$$t_1=[15min]$$
$$t_2=[5min]$$
$$v_0=10[km/h]$$
We immediately see an obstacle to obtain our solution to this equation.
First we have 3 unknowns and 2 equation, thus we cannot solve it yet. Also we notice, that the the units we are making our measurement are not uniform.
We can easily convert the units to be the same:
$$\text{Since 1[min]=}\frac{1}{60}[h]$$
$$t_1=15[min]=\frac{15}{60}[h]=\frac14[h]$$
$$t_2=5[min]=\frac{5}{60}[h]=\frac{1}{12}[h]$$
We also notice the fact, that the distance from towns should not change, as probably the towns are stationary. Therefore:
$$s_{ab}=s_{ba}=s$$
We finally got the equations we can solve, as we have 3 unknowns and 3 equations.

Thus we get:
$$s=t_1(v-v_0)$$
$$s=t_2(v+v_0)$$

Simply adding the terms, we obtain:

$$2s=v(t_1+t_2)+v_o(t_2-t_1)$$
$$2s=\frac13v-\frac16v_0\implies 6s+5=v$$
$$s=\frac14(6s+5-10)\implies 4s=6s-5\implies s=2.5$$
Plugging *s* to either of initial equations, we obtain:

$$v=20[km/h]$$
To obtain time it takes the bus to travel between towns, we simply use:
$$v=\frac st\implies t=\frac sv=0.125[h]=7.5[min]$$

Comment: Sab and Sba need not be the distance between the towns, this incident could have happened with any portion of the whole path.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the space-time diagrams representing the trajectories of the bike and the buses, and the algebraic calculations attached.

Intersections of lines in space diagrams occur when two objects meet in the same place at the same time.

[image]